# Parallel tasks organizer

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

I want to implement a Multithreaded file uploader in C#

1. First I calculate the number of segments for my file based on it's size (1 GB average).
2. I fill a list of the segments IDs for the segments to be uploaded.
3. then I iterate over segments IDs list to upload the segments.
4. if a segment fail I reinsert the segment ID again in it's list.
5. I save that list of segments IDs to support upload continuity (with a workaround here to save also the IDs of in-progress segments).

My problems are:

1. The list that I use to hold my segment ID is a very bad data structure in my case.
2. I want to upload the segments in parallel

The questions now:

- What is the best data structure to use in my case to support parallel processing and keep track of the failed tasks to reschedule it to be processed again?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) is most likely type you are looking for.

[Enqueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287262.aspx) all segments, [TryDequeue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287208.aspx) one that are being processed now, Enqueue failed once again.